# "No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'HelloWorld'"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32 and MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201504301455.

Have created a adapter and tried running it. Getting error:

> No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'HelloWorld'. Possibly the
>   MobileFirst runtime web application for MobileFirst project
>   'HelloWorld' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect
>   the available MBeans. If it is not running, full error details are
>   available in the MobileFirst Development Server Eclipse Console view.

Comment: It is NO MBEAN FOUND FOR MOBILEFIRST PROJECT

Comment: Eclipse folde ris in E , so is WorkSpace is also in E

no special characters in path

Comment: Provide your messages.log file, located at eclipse-worksapce\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\logs

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions/workarounds:

1. Delete the MobileFirstServerConfig

   - Quit Eclipse
   - Navigate to your Eclipse workspace
   - Delete the MobileFirstServerConfig folder
   - Open Eclipse
2. Delete the workspace and start again

   - Delete the workspace
   - Restart Eclipse
   - Re-import the project
3. Try with Eclipse Kepler SR2 32bit/64bit or Eclipse Luna SR2 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Then, I realised I forgot to deploy my adapters.

[image]