# MobileFirst - Problems Deploying Java Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a java adapter in the resource class have the following method(UserAdapterResource.java):

```
public static void init() throws NamingException
ctx = new InitialContext()
ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup (jdbc / mobilefirst_training)
```

And in class UserAdapterApplication.java made the call to init method:

```
UserAdapterResource.init()
```

The problem is that when I make the call to the init method from UserAdapterApplication, the adapter may not deploy, but commented the call to init, the adapter deploy correctly

Which could be the problem?

This is the exception:

```
com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.NotFoundException: FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'LoginModule'. Possibly the MobileFirst runtime web application for MobileFirst project 'LoginModule' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBeans. If it is not running, full error details are available in the log files of the server.
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.RuntimeMBeanRoutingCaller.call(RuntimeMBeanRoutingCaller.java:56)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.validateDeployable(ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.validate(ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.java:217)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.run(BaseTransaction.java:214)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ApplicationService.addApplication(ApplicationService.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:472)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1097)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the error that you get in the messages.log file? What is the error that you see in the Console view in Eclipse?

Comment: Also provide meaningful code and not bits and pieces like in the question. And also confirm that you've actually went over the tutorial using SQL in Java adapters

Comment: This exeption happens when I reboot the server MobileFirst. And when I put the UserAdapterResource.init instruction in UserAdapterApplication.java and saved in the console appears: Adapter deployment failed: null

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'HelloWorld'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228819/no-mbean-found-for-mobilefirst-project-helloworld)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this does not seem to be related to your Java adapter. Possible solutions/workarounds:

1. Delete the MobileFirstServerConfig

   - Quit Eclipse
   - Navigate to your Eclipse workspace
   - Delete the MobileFirstServerConfig folder
   - Open Eclipse
2. Delete the workspace and start again

   - Delete the workspace
   - Restart Eclipse
   - Re-import the project
3. Try with Eclipse Kepler SR2 32bit/64bit or Eclipse Luna SR2 64bit